# Similarities of orthogonal and skew orthogonal

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Does $A^TA=-I$ has the same number of solutions of 2 by 2 matrices $A$ with $A^TA=I$ in $Z_p$ for a fixed $p>2$ ?

Comment: This user and their various incarnations (Terrence Bill etc) have repeatedly asked essentially the same question close to a dozen times now. They have never shared any original thoughts. They show no signs of learning the site rules, and continue to create new accounts to circumvent the earlier question bans/suspensions.

Answer (score 0):

For example: with $p = 5$, we will have 
$$
A^TA = I \iff (2A)^T(2A) = -I
$$
so that the map $A \mapsto 2A$ is a bijection between the solution sets.

A similar trick works whenever $-1$ is a quadratic residue modulo $p$.